# How to add a Management user in JBOSS AS 5.1.0?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss5.x

In JBOSS AS 7.1, they have a script called `add-user.sh` in the `bin` directory. What is its alternative for JBOSS AS 5.1.0? For some reason, I need to use the older version.

I have tried to search for documentation for JBOSS AS 5.1.0 version, and look this up. But I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

In As 5 to login JMX console, add username and password in `$JBOSS_HOME/jboss-as/server/all/conf/props/jmx-console-users.properties` and respective role in `jmx-console-roles.properties`. There is no script to management create user in AS 5.